# Understanding state_dict() in nn.Transformer of PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I am trying to interpret the transformer model. This is the structure of my model:

```
self.src_mask = None
self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(feature_size)
self.encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=feature_size, nhead=nhead, dropout=dropout)
self.transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(self.encoder_layer, num_layers=num_layers)   
self.decoder = nn.Linear(feature_size, output_size)
```

This is an encoder-only transformer model, with a linear decoder layer (please correct me if I'm wrong). I am trying to find the attention passed to the decoder from the encoder.

I tried using state_dict() to find the attention. These are the keys for the last encoder layer:

```
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.self_attn.in_proj_weight
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.self_attn.in_proj_bias
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.self_attn.out_proj.weight
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.self_attn.out_proj.bias
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.linear1.weight
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.linear1.bias
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.linear2.weight
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.linear2.bias
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.norm1.weight
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.norm1.bias
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.norm2.weight
- transformer_encoder.layers.2.norm2.bias
```

I am wondering which of them is the attention passed to the decoder? As I understand, the attention should be the same length as the input. I tried looking for the documentation but couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: These are the layers of the model not the activations.

Comment: @Ivan Hi! Do you know if there is a way to get the attention/activation?

Comment: Which activation are you looking to extract from the inference?

Comment: @Ivan I'm looking for the activation from the last encoder layer to the decoder layer. As this is a transformer, I was thinking that the attention from the encoder to the decoder might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should review the basics of transformers. Your question is hard to answer because it embeds a number of incorrect assumptions. I will attempt to address:

1. The state dict is just a dictionary of model weights. Nothing more or less
2. You are trying to find attention values. These are activations, not weights. Activations must be computed from a specific input
3. There is no "attention passed to the decoder". In encoder-decoder transformers, the decoder model computes attention between the decoder inputs and the output activations of the encoder model. There is no "attention value" passed to the decoder. The decoder is passed the final activations of the encoder model. The decoder uses the final encoder activations to compute different attention values in each layer of the decoder model
4. Attention values are not the same length as the input. Attention values are of shape `(L1, L2)` where `L1` is the length of the encoder sequence and `L2` is the length of the decoder sequence.